# Copy specific cells from one workbook to different cells in another depending on condition

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook called 'EvaluationLog.xlsm' and I need to transfer specific cells (not the whole row) from the first worksheet to another existing workbook called 'IndicatorLog.xlsm' located in the same directory. The target worksheet is also the first one. I'm trying to have the macro hosted in the 'IndicatorLog' workbook.

Specific cells in each row from the source are only to be copied if the contents in column 'O' is 'No' or if the contents of column 'J' is 'Initial'. The actual source data starts on row 8 and the target range also starts on row 8.

I've never had to code in VBA before except for a few very simple tasks, so I'm stuck.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! :)

```
Sub MergeFromLog()

Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim NRow As Long
Dim SourceFileName As String
Dim WorkBk As Workbook
Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer

' Set destination file.
Set TargetSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use as source.
FolderPath = ""

' Set source file.
SourceFileName = FolderPath & "2015-2016 Evaluation Log.xlsm"

' NRow keeps track of where to insert new rows in the destination workbook.
NRow = 8

' Open the source workbook in the folder
Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(SourceFileName)

LastRow = WorkBk.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 8 To LastRow

    If WorkBk.Range(“O” & i) = "No" Or WorkBk.Range(“J” & i) = “Initial” Then

        ' Copy Student Name
        TargetSheet.Range("A" & NRow).Value = WorkBk.Range(“A” & i).Value
        ' Copy DOB
        TargetSheet.Range("B" & NRow).Value = WorkBk.Range(“C” & i).Value
        ' Copy ID#
        TargetSheet.Range("C" & NRow).Value = WorkBk.Range(“D” & i).Value
        ' Copy Consent Day
        TargetSheet.Range("D" & NRow).Value = WorkBk.Range(“L” & i).Value
        ' Copy Report Day
        TargetSheet.Range("E" & NRow).Value = WorkBk.Range(“N” & i).Value
        ' Copy FIE within District Timelines?
        TargetSheet.Range("F" & NRow).Value = WorkBk.Range(“O” & i).Value
        ' Copy Qualified?
        TargetSheet.Range("H" & NRow).Value = WorkBk.Range(“A” & i).Value
        ' Copy Primary Eligibility
        TargetSheet.Range("I" & NRow).Value = WorkBk.Range(“U” & i).Value
        ' Copy ARD Date
        TargetSheet.Range("J" & NRow).Value = WorkBk.Range(“R” & i).Value
        ' Copy ARD within District Timelines?
        TargetSheet.Range("K" & NRow).Value = WorkBk.Range(“S” & i).Value
        ' Copy Ethnicity
        TargetSheet.Range("M" & NRow).Value = WorkBk.Range(“F” & i).Value
        ' Copy Hisp?
        TargetSheet.Range("N" & NRow).Value = WorkBk.Range(“G” & i).Value
        ' Copy Diag/LSSP
        TargetSheet.Range("O" & NRow).Value = WorkBk.Range(“X” & i).Value

        NRow = NRow + 1

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your specific problem?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't seem to do anything. :(

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to determine where it is not doing anything?

Comment: I'm guessing that the value of `LastRow` is <= 8, so the `For i = 8 to lastRow` loop is simply not executing.

Comment: David, I think you guided me in the right direction. Now I'm getting this error: 'Object doesn't support this property of method' in the following line:

TargetSheet.Range("A" & NRow).Value = WorkBk.Range(“A” & i).Value

Comment: Using WorkBk.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row will only get you the last row that has data in column A.  Try WorkBk.ActiveSheet.usedrange.Rows.Count.

Comment: UsedRange is notoriously unreliable method for finding the last row :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a range has to refer to a sheet.

Change

```
If WorkBk.Range(“O” & i) = "No" Or WorkBk.Range(“J” & i) = “Initial” Then
```

To

```
If WorkBk.ActiveSheet.Range("O" & i) = "No" Or WorkBk.ActiveSheet.Range("J" & i) = "Initial" Then
```

Comment: Good catch -- if her code is executing it will raise a 438 error on that line, but this is not the error that OP has, which is "code not doing anything".  She will need to step through her code and figure out why the `For` loop is not executing.

Comment: Thank you both! Your answers helped me! Now I'm getting this error: 'Object doesn't support this property of method' in the following line: TargetSheet.Range("A" & NRow).Value = WorkBk.Range(“A” & i).Value

Comment: Wasn't sure if the error would raise if "Option explicit" was not used.

Comment: @MatthewD it will raise an error, but it won't raise a compile error so the code can actually execute as long as those statements aren't executed.

Comment: Same issue. Change   WorkBk.Range("A" & i).Value to WorkBk.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value

Comment: @David Zemens Thanks for the info.

Comment: I truly appreciate all your help, guys!! I'm finally making progress thanks to you!! Now I'm getting this error: Application-defined or object-defined error (1004)' in the same line: TargetSheet.Range("A" & NRow).Value = WorkBk.ActiveSheet.Range(“A” & i).Value

Comment: Is your code "behind" one of the sheets?  This may be a problem with it wanting to write to the active sheet.  I don't get any error and i have the code behind a form.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew! I'm not sure. :(  I entered the code by going to Macros and clicking on 'Create'. Should I be doing something different?

Comment: Matthew, I think I know what you meant now. I added a button and assigned the macro to the button, but I still got the same error. Not sure what to do now. :/

Comment: I'm not sure.  I would open a new question with your code in it's current condition and the title of the error you are getting and copying data from one sheet to another.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the value of `LastRow` is <= 8, so the `For i = 8 to lastRow` loop is simply not executing.

For better method of finding the last row, refer here:

[Error in finding last used cell in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920)

If it were executing, most of the statements within the loop will raise a 438 error, as @MatthewD notes in his answer, the `Workbook` object does not have a `Range` method, you would have to qualify `.Range` to a specific `Worksheet` object within the workbook.

All of the statements like `... WorkBk.Range(...` must be changed to something like:

`... WorkBk.ActiveSheet.Range(...`

Comment: This helped me get rid of the previous error!! Thanks! :)